# Evaluating the integral $\int\frac{2x^3+x^2+1}{x^2+x-2}\space dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

As suggested in the title, I am given the following integral:

$$\int\frac{2x^3+x^2+1}{x^2+x-2}\space dx$$

I have tried to solve it several times, but I wind up with the wrong answer, although its close. I assume there is a blunder somewhere.

Applying long division, we have that

$$\frac{2x^3+x^2+1}{x^2+x-2} = 2x - 1 + \frac{-3x-1}{x^2+x-2}$$

I note now that I may write this as

$$\frac{2x^3+x^2+1}{x^2+x-2} = 2x - 1 + \frac{(-1)3x+1}{x^2+x-2} = 2x - 1 - \frac{3x+1}{x^2+x-2}$$

I did not notice this while doing the task originally, but I am having a hard time seeing how this will make answer different. (After calculating it on paper: it didn't.)

Thus, we have the integral

$$\int 2x - 1 \space dx - \int \frac{3x+1}{x^2+x-2}\space dx$$

The first integral is trivial. For the second one, we have that

$$\frac{3x+1}{(x-1)(x+2)} = \frac{A}{x-1} + \frac{B}{x+2} = \frac{A(x+2)+B(x-1)}{(x-1)(x+2)}$$

We have the set $A + B = 3, \space 2A - B = 1$.This gives us the solutions $A = \frac{4}{3}$ and $B = \frac{5}{3}$

Thus, we are left with

$x^2 - x - \int \frac{3x+1}{x^2+x-2}\space dx = x^2 - x - \int \frac{4/3}{x-1} + \frac{5/3}{x+2} \space dx = x^2 - x - \frac{4}{3}\ln{|x-1|}-\frac{5}{3}\ln{|x+2|} + C$

I'm having a hard time finding my mistake here.

EDIT: Seems like I made my mistake in the long division part, confirming now.

Comment: The long division is incorrect. Check your signs. The numerator in the remainder term should be $5x-1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're off at the start, with your long division: in particular, the numerator of the remainder needs to be $5x - 1$.

$$\frac{2x^3+x^2+0\cdot x +1}{x^2+x-2} = 2x - 1 + \frac{5x - 1}{x^2+x-2} = 2x - 1 + \frac{5x-1}{(x+2)(x-1)}$$
Procedurally, your approach is just fine: once you correct for this mistake, you should obtain the correct result.

Note also that in the logarithm components of your answer, we can "consolidate":

$$a\ln |f(x)| + b\ln |g(x)| = \ln|(f(x))^a| + \ln|(g(x))^b| = \ln|(f(x))^a\cdot (g(x))^b|$$

and$$a\ln |f(x)| - b\ln |g(x)| = \ln|(f(x))^a| - \ln|(g(x))^b| = \ln\left|\dfrac{(f(x))^a}{(g(x))^b}\right|$$

Comment: For me this is a perfect answer! +1 :-)

Comment: @amWhy: very nice feedback! +1

Answer (score 0):

The remainder after long division is $5x - 1$; when you do long division, make sure you account for the 'missing' $x$ in the numerator: $2x^3 + x^2 + 0x + 1$.